# Plot subplots borderless - more than 10 subplots in a row

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a bunch of images out of a data frame. But I'm struggling right now with two Problems. This is the part of my script in which the pictures should be plotted.

```
nrows = len(df.index)
ncols = len(df.columns)
plotindex = 1
for row in df.index:
    for col in df.columns:
        plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, plotindex)
        x = Image.open(df[row][col])
        x = x.resize((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        plt.imshow(x)
        plt.axis('off')
        plotindex += 1
        
plt.show()
```

1. It raises an valueError, when i want to plot more than 9 subplots(images) in a row. Is it possible to plot more than 9 subplots in a row/column?
2. I'm struggling with the adjustment of the subplots. I want the subplots/images to align borderless and i don't know how to adjust the size of the whole figure correctly. (Without destroying the grid). Does anyone know a better solution to organise the grid?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
nrows, ncols = df.shape
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)
for row in range(nrows):
    for col in range(ncols):
        x = Image.open(df.iloc[row, col])
        x = x.resize((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        axes[row,col].imshow(x)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. It is now possible to use more than 9 subplots. I will try to adjust the grid with this setting now.